# How to use scala and html code inside single block

Tags: html, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scala-template

why option html element is not binded inside select in case 1?

Case 1: not work

```
@base{
  <select name="" value="" class="custom-select">
  @{
    println("1"); // this is printed to console             
    <option value="test">i</option> // this is not shown in html
    println("2"); // this is printed to console                     
  }
  </select>
}
```

Case 2: work

```
@base{
  <select name="" value="" class="custom-select">
  @{
    println("1"); // this is printed to console             
    <option value="test">i</option> // this is shown in html                    
  }
  </select>
}
```

Update:

How one can create a loop which binds all option elements to scala template? Following code does not bind any option elements. What is actually return type? Empty line?

```
<select name="" value="" class="custom-select">
@{
    for(i <- 1 to 10) {
        <option value="@i">@i</option>
    }
}
</select>
```

Comment: In scala, last statement of the block treated as return result, in your first case you'll get Unit aka void (result of println) and option is simply thrown away

Answer (score 2):

The code block `@{...}` is a closure that has an inferred return type from the last statement.

In the first case the return type is inferred to be `Unit` since the `println(...)` returns `Unit`

In the second block the html is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the first question directly, but assuming that @korefn and @om-nom-nom are correct; that the block is a closure and is interpreting the return as a void.

In response to your update, I would try:

```
@for(i <- 1 to 10) {
    <option value="@i">@i</option>
}
```

which is how I've used it in the past.  I've also found it helpful to use a nested @if block to handle the selected option differently so that it is selected on loading the document.

Comment: I have already realized @for solution works, but I would like to understand how to do this using @{...} closure. Reason for this is that I must write around 10 lines of scala code before for loop. These 10 lines create list, which will be looped.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'm new to scala, but by the logic above, wouldn't adding the options to a collection using a loop and then mapping the collection to a print statement on the last line of the block work?

Comment: I was also thinking about using print statement, but didn't understand how to do that. I am super newbie in Scala.

Comment: Yeah, me too. The block construct has piqued my interest though, so thanks for introducing me to that.  I'm going to play around a bit, and if I get the expected output I'll edit my answer.  If you figure it out first ping me, I'd like to see a working approach.